# Set accelerometer to user position

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi how can i set the accelerometer 0 point to the users position/the angel he is holding it ?
I am using :

```
delta = -40/180*math.pi  --
cos_delta, sin_delta = math.cos(delta), math.sin(delta)
```

To offset is, but hos can i make it that the angel the device is holed is the 0

#

extra code :

```
    -- Speed of Movement with tilt. You can change it ans see the effects.
    tiltSpeed           = 30;
    motionx             = 0;
    motiony             = 0;
    rotation            = 0;


    --delta = -50/180*math.pi  -- 30 degrees, maybe should have minus sign
    --cos_delta, sin_delta = math.cos(delta), math.sin(delta)

-- Firstly, you need to get accelerometer's values in "zero position"
-- probably, inside onTilt event
local gy, gz = event.yGravity, event.zGravity 
local len = math.sqrt(gy*gy+gz*gz) * (gz < 0 and -1 or 1)
cos_delta = gz / len
sin_delta = -gy / len

local function onTilt(event)
    motionx = tiltSpeed * event.xGravity
    motiony = tiltSpeed * (cos_delta*event.yGravity + sin_delta*event.zGravity)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Firstly, you need to get accelerometer's values in "zero position"
-- probably, inside onTilt event
local gy, gz = event.yGravity, event.zGravity 

-- Secondly, update your cos_delta and sin_delta to remember "zero position"
local len = math.sqrt(gy*gy+gz*gz) * (gz < 0 and -1 or 1)
cos_delta = gz / len
sin_delta = -gy / len
```

Comment: is this to replace "delta = -40/180*math.pi  cos_delta, sin_delta = math.cos(delta), math.sin(delta)" ?

Comment: getting this error "game.lua Line: 319 Attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'gy' (a nil value)"

Comment: Calculations involving `gy`, `gz` should be inside onTilt event, but only when user asked you to set new zero position (inside `if`).